# What kind of breaks do I use when i want to make a map with data that has a lognormal distribution

Tags: r, dictionary, plot, distribution

I have a number of positions with assigned values, where a lot of the numbers are near 0 and very few are high. Similar to a lognormal distribution. I want to plot them in a heatmap, but Im not sure how to set the breaks. Im making the map in mapplots, using colorbrewer. Here is an example of how I thought it could be done - but is this sound?

```
library(RColorBrewer)
library(mapplots)

set.seed(10)
d <- data.frame(x=rlnorm(1000,meanlog = -0.75, sdlog = 1.5), Lon=runif(1000), Lat=runif(1000))
byx = 0.05
byy = 0.05
xlim<-c(0,1)
ylim<-c(0,1)

intervals <- (c(0,1,2,5,10,20,50,100,200,500,1000,2000,5000, 10000, 20000)/100)
grd <- make.grid(d$Lon,d$Lat,d$x,byx, byy, xlim, ylim)

maxvalue <- max(unlist(grd), na.rm = T)
breaks <- unlist(lapply(maxvalue,function(x) c(intervals[intervals< x], x)))

col <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9, "YlOrRd"))(length(breaks)-1)

basemap(xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim, main = "", bg="grey")
draw.grid(grd, breaks=breaks,col=col)
legend.grid("topright", xpd=F, breaks=breaks, type=2, col=col, bg="white")
```

You get a map like this:

[image: You get a map like this]

The distribution of points in the map is like this:

```
hist(unlist(grd), 50)
```

[image]

Comment: Log-transform your data?

Comment: I want to present my data like they are. Its fish abundances.

Comment: The heatmap you present is basically what you'd get if you log-transformed your data and let the computer pick the breaks for you.

Comment: But how would I write the legend then. -2^10, -1^10 etc or...? The question is what breaks do i choose.

Comment: Nothing wrong with it as-is imo.

Comment: So what i hear you say is that you can pretty much choose whatever breaks you want? As long as they make sense.